# Не работает свойство textContent

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой элемент

```
<button class="b1"> I am button 1 </button>
```

Нужно в JS с помощью textContent поменять текст на кнопке при клике. Делаю таким образом

```
let b1 = document.querySelector('.b1')
b1.onclick = function (){
    this.style.textContent = 'I am changed button 1'
}
```

В итоге текст при клике не изменяется, консоль ошибок не выдает. Другие же свойства, например, background 'orange' работают нормально

Comment: style уберите .

Comment: this.textContent = 'I am changed button 1'

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @andreymal: оформите ответом, раз уж подвесили вопрос.

Comment: @UModeL это опечатка, вопрос на закрытие